# ggplot2 return values

Tags: r, ggplot2

The documentation for `ggplot2`'s `stat_bin` function states that it **returns** a new data frame with additional columns. How does one actually get access to this data frame?

Is it possible?

```
simple <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, each = 2))
tmp <- stat_bin(data=simple, binwidth=0.1, aes(x))
```

I have figured out that `tmp` is an environment, and `ls(tmp)` will show what objects are in the environment, but after exploring each of these objects, I'm not seeing anything like what is described as a return value.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think that the calculation are done when your print it and it isn't easlly accesible to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ggplot2 (3.3.5)`, I can not get access to the returned data frame with `ggplot2:::print.ggplot()`, but I get success with `ggplot_build`:

```
simple <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, each = 2))
tmp <- ggplot(data=simple) + stat_bin(aes(x), binwidth=0.1)
# with ggplot_build
x <- ggplot_build(tmp)
head(x[["data"]][[1]])
#   y count   x xmin xmax density ncount ndensity flipped_aes PANEL group ymin ymax colour   fill size linetype alpha
# 1 2     2 1.0 0.95 1.05       1      1        1       FALSE     1    -1    0    2     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
# 2 0     0 1.1 1.05 1.15       0      0        0       FALSE     1    -1    0    0     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
# 3 0     0 1.2 1.15 1.25       0      0        0       FALSE     1    -1    0    0     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
# 4 0     0 1.3 1.25 1.35       0      0        0       FALSE     1    -1    0    0     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
# 5 0     0 1.4 1.35 1.45       0      0        0       FALSE     1    -1    0    0     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
# 6 0     0 1.5 1.45 1.55       0      0        0       FALSE     1    -1    0    0     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
```

Answer (score 9):

**NOTE:** With the current (as of 2022-05-24) version of **ggplot2** (3.3.6), the approach described below no longer works. In place of `print(tmp)` , you should now use `ggplot_build(tmp)`, as noted in @showteth's now-accepted answer.

---

As Luciano Selzer mentions, the calculations that produce the table shown below aren't  performed until print time. (A look at `ggplot2:::print.ggplot()` will show that, in its final line, it returns the table invisibly, so it can be captured by assignment for further examination.)

```
tmp <- ggplot(data=simple) + stat_bin(aes(x), binwidth=0.1)
x <- print(tmp)
head(x[["data"]][[1]])
#   y count    x ndensity ncount density PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax
# 1 0     0 0.95        0      0       0     1     1    0    0  0.9  1.0
# 2 2     2 1.05        1      1       1     1     1    0    2  1.0  1.1
# 3 0     0 1.15        0      0       0     1     1    0    0  1.1  1.2
# 4 0     0 1.25        0      0       0     1     1    0    0  1.2  1.3
# 5 0     0 1.35        0      0       0     1     1    0    0  1.3  1.4
# 6 0     0 1.45        0      0       0     1     1    0    0  1.4  1.5
```

Comment: The returned data.frame doesn't exist until paired with a `ggplot` call and "printed"?  From the OPs example, `get('data', env=tmp)` returns just the passed in `sample` data.frame.

Comment: Partly, yes. But it still doesn't seem to fit what R means when it says it **returns** a value. It just doesn't seem like it should be so hard to get at values generated by a function.

Comment: In contrast, I can do `tmp <- hist(simple, breaks=100, plot=F)` and have access to everything in a list in `tmp`

Comment: @rmflight -- I also happen to find **ggplot2**'s internals maddeningly hard to inspect. That said, waiting until print-time to finalize these tables seems like a great design decision, especially given that ggplot's designed to update and extend plots on the fly. No point in performing those calculations until the user has made their final addition of a `+ stat_*()` clause...

Comment: Also, *once you know it's there*, `x <- print(tmp)` is no harder to do than `tmp <- hist(simple)`. (It would be nice, though, if `?print.ggplot` at least indicated (as `?hist` does) that it does have a return value.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yes, ggplot internal are I pain to inspect and there's no documentation on how it works.

Comment: @rmflight These are good points about the docs. If I have some free time this weekend, I'll try to add a pull request to address them.

Comment: There's not much point in trying to document the existing internals because even I don't understand them very well.  For the next release Winston and I will be working on a re-write that should be simpler and easier to extend (and it will be possible to call all stat functions to get the results outside of a plot)