# Understanding the "ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead" error in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + stat_bin(binwidth=0.1, geom="bar") # No error
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + stat_bin(binwidth=0.1, geom="point") # "ymax not defined"
```

The error is produced from `ggplot2`'s `position-collide.R` ([link](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-collide.r#L41-L44)):

```
  if (!is.null(data$ymax)) {
    ddply(data, "xmin", strategy, width = width)
  } else if (!is.null(data$y)) {
    message("ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead")
```

From the source code above, it seems that this message appears because `ggplot2` checks and there is no `ymax` in the data. However, it doesn't make sense why `ymax` exists in the first plot but not in the second. Both plots use `stat_bin`, [which produces a data frame with `ymax, ymin`, and other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267970/ggplot2-return-values).

So why does this message appear in the second plot?

Comment: My understanding is that one uses `stat_bin` to control bin width. I am not sure if points have bin width.

Comment: @jazzurro That's not really relevant here. The `binwidth` options decides how many bins there are in the plots. If there are 10 bins, there will be 10 bars and 10 points. It has nothing to do with the `ymax` issue.

Comment: If you type this in your R Console, you would not see `ymax`.  `p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(); ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]`. I think this suggests that `stat_bin` requires ymax, but when one draws data points with `geom_point` ggplot is not calculating `ymax`; it is not in the data frame that ggplot creates. On the other hand, you will see `ymax` in the following example. `a <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + stat_bin(binwidth=0.1, geom="bar"); ggplot_build(a)$data[[1]]`